# sql join table with a select statement

Tags: sql, join

i have a table with codes like

```
0100 ABC
0100 ASD
9010 ABC
5555 ABC
```

i want to create  select statement, that will bring me two columns like

```
calumn A (all the codes starting with 0100), column B (all the codes that after the first 4 chars, have the same ending with column A)
```

example

```
0100 ABC, 9010 ABC
0100 ABC, 5555 ABC
0100 ASD, null
```

i was thinking like

```
select mtr.code, mtr1.code
from material mtr
where mtr.code like (%+

select distinct  substring(mtr.code,5, len(mtr.code)) code
from material mtr1 

)
```

but of course it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Is 0100 a value of a single column, or 0100 ABC is the value of the column? Could you please share the table design?

Comment: LIKE subquery cannot return more than 1 value, looks like it may return more as you are using DISTINCT

Comment: table material has only one column string, so 0100 ABC and anything else is a single value in that table

Comment: `(%+` is invalid SQL

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
select m1.code, m2.code
from material m1
left outer join material m2
    on substring(m1.code from 5) = substring(m2.code from 5)
    and m1.id <> m2.id
where m1.code like '0100%'
```

We use a `left outer join` to get all rows from `material`, even the ones who have no twins. Our join condition is that the two `code` values must be identical after the first 4 characters. The code also assumes that there is an `id` column; it's used to avoid joining a row to itself.

On the other hand, if `code` is your primary key, then `m1.code <> m2.code` should be used instead.